# Checking for nil parameter and if that parameter is an empty string in Swift

Tags: swift, react-native

There may or may not be an easier way to write this, but I feel like being a novice at Swift, I am probably missing something. I have a parameter (fileName) for a method that is an optional `String?` I need to check if it is `nil`, or if it is an empty String. This is the code I have, and it works fine, but it seems like it could be a bit more concise/readable.

```
func writeFile(fileName: String?, withContents contents: String, errorCallback failureCallback: RCTResponseSenderBlock, callback successCallback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {

  // If fileName has a value -- is not nil
  if let fileName = fileName {
    // Check to see if the string isn't empty
    if count(fileName) < 1 {
      // Craft a failure message
      let resultsDict = [
        "success": false,
        "errMsg": "Filename is empty"
      ]

      // Execute the JavaScript failure callback handler
      failureCallback([resultsDict])

      return; // Halt execution of this function
    }
    // else, fileName is nil, and should return the same error message.
  } else {
    // Craft a failure message
    let resultsDict = [
      "success": false,
      "errMsg": "Filename is empty"
    ]

    // Execute the JavaScript failure callback handler
    failureCallback([resultsDict])

    return; // Halt execution of this function
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

First create a nil string optional to set up the example
    var fileName: String?

Now code that lets you see if filename is nil/empty in one simple line:

```
if (fileName ?? "").isEmpty
{
  println("empty")
}
else
{
  println("not empty")
}
```

This uses `??`, the Swift "[**nil coalescing operator**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72)". (link)

For the expression:

```
a ?? b
```

Where `a` is an optional it says:

if a is not nil, return a. If a is nil, return b instead.

So

```
if (fileName ?? "").isEmpty
```

Says

First, evaluate fileName and see if it's nil. If so, replace it with an empty string.

Next, check the result to see if it's empty.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct since it got me there, but would you mind getting rid of the first line (I'm not sure it's needed) and the original parameter name is `fileName`, not `filename`

Also, would you mind giving a brief explanation as to what the `??` for future people who may come across this.

Comment: It is called nil coalescing operator

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

Comment: The nil coalescing operator is not unique to Swift, as may be implied in the answer.

Comment: @DuncanC 'First create a nil string optional to set up the example var fileName: String?' that line is a bit confusing because fileName is already a String? optional as it is a parameter set in the function declaration...so I don't believe that's needed. The rest of the code works fine though, thanks!

Comment: Kevin, I provided a few lines of sample code that stand alone and show what the nil coalescing operator does. I wasn't giving you code that you could copy/paste into your program.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right approach. All you need to do is combine your IF statements into one line:

```
func writeFile(fileName: String?, withContents contents: String, errorCallback failureCallback: RCTResponseSenderBlock, callback successCallback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {
  // Check if fileName is nil or empty
  if (fileName == nil) || (fileName != nil && count(fileName!) < 1) {
    // Craft a failure message
    let resultsDict = [
      "success": false,
      "errMsg": "Filename is empty"
    ]

    // Execute the JavaScript failure callback handler
    failureCallback([resultsDict])

    return; // Halt execution of this function
  }

  // Perform code here since fileName has a value and is not empty
}
```

This code first checks if `fileName` is `nil`. If so, it goes into the failure block. If not, it goes to the second conditional. In the second conditional, it will go into the failure block if `fileName` has a value and is empty. Only when `fileName` has a value and is NOT empty will it skip the failure block.

Comment: I actually tried that, and receive the following error: Could not find an overload for '==' that accepts the supplied arguments

Comment: Fixed the IF statement. Writing the explanation now.

Comment: Yep...this one works as well now.  I already marked Duncan's as working, but may switch it to this one depending on whether or not he makes the corrections to his.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine your `if let` and `if` statement into something like this:

```
if let str = fileName where !str.isEmpty {
    println(str)
} else {
    println("empty")
}
```

This approach is useful if you need to use the filename after checking whether it's `nil` or empty.